# Alternative way to pass list to HttpGet Method in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, parameter-passing

I need to pass a list(containing at least 3 items) to MVC HttpGet Action... but i don't know how to pass that... Is there any other way instead of using Request Query String? using Request Query String is off the chart for me, since the list is created dynamically in client side..

```
    public ActionResult Customer(List customer)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

please guide me through this... Thanks in advance..

Comment: what sort of data does it need to send from the user? full customer data (firstname,lastname,etc)? or just a list of existing customer ids?

Comment: @arserbin3 I need to pass Id, Name, DOB,Address, City, Country, Email & other basic details in a list..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by manually parsing the `FormCollection` object, but it would make for tedious code. However this may be necessary if you can't control the names of the POSTed values.

```
public ActionResult Customer(FormCollection response)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < response["CustomerCount"]; i++
    {
        list.Add(
            new Customer
            {
                ID = response["Customer" + i + ".ID"],
                Name = response["Customer" + i + ".Name"],
                ...
            });
    }
}
```

But a much cleaner way is using MVC's automatic binding, which works for lists as well:

The query string from user:

```
/Customer/Add?myList[0].ID=2&myList[0].Name=Bob&myList[1].ID=18&myList[1].Name=Alice
```

The controller:

```
public CustomerController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Add(List<Customer> myList)
    {
        var test = myList.Count; // 2
        var test2 = myList[1].Name; // Alice
    }
}
```

If possible, using the `HtmlHelper` methods in your Razor view to create those inputs, takes all the guesswork out of this. An example to edit current customers:

```
@model MyNamespace.ViewModels.CustomerEditViewModel
@Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Customer")
{
    @* Show all current customers for editing *@
    @for (int i=0; i < Model.Customers.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Customers[i].ID)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Customers[i].Name)
    }

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Note: Customers is a `List<Customer>` in the `CustomerEditViewModel` class passed with `return View(myViewModel);`

Comment: Thank u so much @arserbin3 .. I used ur idea and it worked well.. No words to express my gratitude.. Once again, Thank u, My friend... :-)

Comment: I have another doubt in the method u mentioned. Querystring has length constraint.... so is there any other way??

Comment: the other (and better) way is to be submitting the data as a `POST` request instead of a `GET`. `POST` data has no length limit. You should then consider adding `[HttpPost]` attribute to the `Add()` action